# Script to Generate PDF from Google Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'd previously written a script for a google sheet that triggered when its related google form had a form submitted. When the form was submitted, a PDF would generate and be emailed to the designated person. I created a new version to auto-generate a Digital Millennium Copyright Act notice, but something seems to not work with the script anymore (the original isn't working anymore either) and I can't figure out how to fix it.

The error I'm getting is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")**

---

9/28/2021 I added `console.log(rg.getA1Notation())` to the code as instructed and submitted a form. The Execution log for it shows me the below -
[image]

Code below -

````
  const rg = e.range;
  console.log(rg.getA1Notation());
  const sh = rg.getSheet();
  
  //Get all the form submitted data
  const Email= e.namedValues['Email Address'][0];
  const LinkOrig = e.namedValues['Link(s) for where the original work appears'][0];
  const AttachOrig = e.namedValues['Copies of the original copyrighted work'][0];
  const Domain = e.namedValues['Infringing Domain'][0];
  const LinkInfring = e.namedValues['Link(s) for where infringing image appears online'][0];
  const Contact = e.namedValues['Contact Information'][0];
  const WHOIS = e.namedValues['WHOIS Search results'][0];
  const Date = e.namedValues['Date'][0];
  const Location = e.namedValues['Where are you based?'][0];
  
  //Build a new DMCA Form from the template
  //Folder ID (save destination) and file IDs (template ID + new doc ID)
  const DMCAFolderID = 'googledrivefolderidhere';
  const DMCALibFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DMCAFolderID);
  
  const TemplateFileID = 'googledrivetemplateidhere';
  const newFilename = 'DMCA Notice -' + TemplateFileID + 'Domain';
  
  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newTemplateFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, DMCALibFolder).getId();;
  
  //Get the DMCA Notice body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplateFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();
  
  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the BlinkLib body
  body.replaceText('{{LinkOrig}}', LinkOrig);
 // body.replaceText('{{AttachOrig}}', AttachOrig);
  body.replaceText('{{LinkInfring}}', LinkInfring);
  body.replaceText('{{ContactInfo}}', Contact);
  body.replaceText('{{WHOISResults}}', WHOIS);
  body.replaceText('{{date}}', Date);
  body.replaceText('{{location}}', Location);
  
  document.saveAndClose();

// define email variables
var subject = 'DMCA Notice - ' + Domain;
var msgHtml = 
"Hi " + Name + "," + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Please find your DMCA Notice attached." + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Sincerely," + "<br/>" +
"Your Bada** Self" + "<br/>" 
;
var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(newTemplateFileID);

//send email with the file
GmailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, msgHtml, {htmlBody: msgHtml, attachments: [attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`  indicates that you are trying to run your code manually
- However, `const rg = e.range;` indicates that you are retrieving the range as an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) - which can be retrieved only when a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) fires

Summary:

**When using event objects like `e.range` you cannot run your code manually, you need to let the execution be triggered automatically. This implies that your funciton is being called on a trigger - e.g. an `onEdit` trigger.**

Comment: Do you mean, it needs to be run from a form submission? I have run it that way and it still isn't working that way either. The error I see in the execution log says the same... 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
    at onSubmit(Code:2:16)

Comment: So is your function tied to a formSubmit trigger? And is the script bound to a spreadsheet or a form?

Comment: The function is tied to a formSubmit trigger, yes. The script is bound to the spreadsheet.

Comment: If the code is triggered automatically when a form response is submitted, you should not get this type of error. Double-check if the timestamp of the error matches the form submission event. Implement some logs into your code, e.g. console.log(RG.getA1Notation())` and place this line after `const rg = e.range;`. Then, after submitting a form response go on `View->Executions` and expand the execution with the timestamp matching the form submit event.

Comment: I added the log in my code as you suggested. I can't include a screenshot in my comment here so I added a screenshot of the Execution for the matching form submit event in my original post.

Comment: You can see from the logs that the error is now a different one and occurs in line 47. I assume it is the line `var msgHtml = 
"Hi " + Name + "," + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Please find your DMCA Notice attached." + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Sincerely," + "<br/>" +
"Your Bada** Self" + "<br/>" `. As the error states `Name` is not defined - because you did not define in your code a variable called `Name`.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that's that Code: 47:9 meant. Oh my goodness, I feel so silly. I was pouring over this for days, confused as to why it wasn't working. It finally worked for the first time today and I'm so excited :) :) :) THANK YOU!